# PHP MySQL updates without having a right value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new with MySQL and I have a problem. I have a database etc. that works perfectly fine. I can update emails but it doesn't recognize if there isn't a value to update.

php

```
if (isset($_POST['updateemail'])) {
    $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sname']);
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['useremail']);

    if($sname == "" && $fname == ""){
        echo "<br> Name can not be empty";
} else {

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET email = '$email' WHERE surename = '$sname' OR firstname = '$fname'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo "<br> Email updated!";
    } else {
        echo "<br> Email update not succesful.";
        echo "<br> Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

I also have another code which is somewhat similar to this one but it doesn't have the "or" and it also doesn't recognize if there isn't a name what I've typed..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't recognize if there isn't a value to update"?

Comment: You just need to run another query to search for the user first, but guess that you have lot of users with 'John' as first name, all of them will be updated with that email.

Comment: If I insert a value (firstname or surename) in html it doesn't matter if it is in the database or not - it still shows "Email updated!" whatever I type in it and after clicking update.

Comment: mysqli_query() returns true if query was executed, no matter if records were updated or not.

Comment: I'd appreciate an example - I really don't know how to do that (really just a beginner).. it doesn't really matter if everyone with the same first name will update but I'd prefer not @Triby

Comment: You could search by id and not by surename & firstname. Make an id field which is AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: cmsia I've added an answer filtering by surename and firstname, but there's still a possiblity to find more than 1 user. I'd like the suggestion made by @Codew about an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)`

Change your

```
if ($result) {
        echo "<br> Email updated!";
    }
```

To this

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
            echo "<br> Email updated!";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['updateemail'])) {
    $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sname']);
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['useremail']);

    if($sname == "" && $fname == ""){
        echo "<br> Name can not be empty";
} else {
    // Search for valid user
    $sql = "SELECT table WHERE surename = '$sname' AND firstname = '$fname'";
    $found = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Can't search for user: "  . mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($found) == 1) {
        // User found, let's update
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET email = '$email' WHERE surename = '$sname' AND firstname = '$fname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($result) {
            echo "<br> Email updated!";
        } else {
            echo "<br> Email update not succesful.";
            echo "<br> Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<br> User not found!";
    }
}
```